# I need a validator that can read all html pages and validate the markup in locally

Tags: php, html, markup, validation

I need a markup validator that can read all html pages and validate the markup in locally. W3C Service is good but the problem is it is very slow when have 10-20 html pages. any one know free markup validator.

Comment: In a comment you wrote that you "need to build validator in same web site what are going to check", in the question it says "locally". You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the w3c validator and have it run locally http://validator.w3.org/source/

Comment: Sorry i need to build validator in same web site what are going to check

Comment: I used this one but the problem is when checking 10 to 20 pages it is very slow